# Show updated xy coordinates 'live'?

Tags: arcobjects, coordinate-system, add-in, xy

I want to create add-in tool to show x y coordinate on status bar live.

```c#
      protected override void OnMouseMove(ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool.MouseEventArgs arg)
    {

        //this.Enabled = !this.Enabled;
        ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = null;


        if (ArcMap.Document == null || ArcMap.Document.CurrentLocation == null)
            return;

        var point = ArcMap.Document.CurrentLocation;
        ArcMap.Application.StatusBar.set_Message(0, point.X.ToString() + point.Y.ToString());
    }
```

but xy are not live. What should i do?

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you mean with "status bar"? Could you post a screen shot to show what you want? 
Whitout knowing the above, why isn't the built-in coordinate display in the lower right corner in Arcmap sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Now,I'm OK. I deleted `ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = null;`